# How to compile different code for different JDK version?

Tags: java

For avoiding [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/):

The original question is, I want to develop a Java library in Java 21, but with support for Java 8.

Then, I want to release a Java library, with 2 different Java versions, 8 and 21, with one single repository (to avoid massive code duplication) and some configurations, where the 21 version has some optimizations (languages spec, new API, etc), and 8 has fallback (non-optimized) implementations.

I have thought several methods:

1. <del>Use two repository / module</del>.

   - Pros: Easy to configure.
   - Cons: High code duplication percentage (Decisive).
2. <del>Use macro</del>.

   - Pros: Easy to write, like C/C++.
   - Cons: Java have NO macro (However... it seems a Java "dialect" for [Blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4509881/9035237) [Development](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9042007/9035237) has some macros, but I don't want to modify JDK).
3. Use runtime Java version as branch condition.

   - Pros: What [Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION) [does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7373542/9035237).
   - Cons: Checks everywhere, hits only one branch for every single JRE version, and branching may cause [performance questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/9035237).
4. Use annotation processor to mark "which code should compile".

   - Pros: Theoretically achievable.
   - Cons: Seems hard to implement.
5. Write implementations in different file, then control which file to compile.

   - Pros: I am using Gradle, this may be possible to achieve by using `sourceSets` tweaking.
   - Cons: Tweaking in Gradle is always hard.

Then, there are several questions:

1. How to compile different code for different JDK version?
2. Is 1 achievable with @Annotation Processor?
3. Is 1 optimized for the original question?

I use [Gradle Kts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) build system, and the main source code are all Java.

Comment: *The original question is, I want to develop a Java library in Java 21, but with support for Java 8.* Don't. This is not a rational thing to do. You could use a different language that targets the Java 8 JVM. That's reasonable. But don't try and write Java 21 that is also Java 8.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch is "writing implementations differently for 8 and 21, where 21 uses new spec, but 8 use traditional spec" reasonable?

Comment: Not really. You're going to struggle because, as you have discovered, there are absolutely no tools to enable that. Let's extend your request, why aren't you going to support Java 8, 11, 17 and 21? Those are all LTS releases. But now you have four code bases, or one code base with four disparate implementations.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch In C/C++, we can use macros to control "what code should compile" with `#if`, `#ifdef`, `#ifndef`, etc. If the macro has condition using `__GLIBC__`, `__GNUC__`, etc., then we have the "tool" for doing so, and this has been used in several repos, for example [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/boost/config/compiler/gcc.hpp). So I think this is a reasonable solution for C/C++. But why this is not reasonable for Java?

Comment: Because Java is not C++.  It's just the way it is.

Comment: Because when Java was being designed, the designers held that preprocessors were a horrible kludge that resulted in code that was hard to understand and maintain.  (Especially when macros, conditional compilation, etc are used injudiciously.)  Not supporting source code preprocessing was a deliberate design decision.   (I wish I could find the old articles on the Java design rationale ... but they appear to have vanished from the public internet.)

Comment: Assuming this is something you _need_ to do, have you considered [multi-release JAR files](https://openjdk.org/jeps/238)?

Comment: I agree with Slaw.  Multi-release jars exist for this very task.

Answer (score 0):

This is a extensible but not-so-clean solution by tweaking Gradle [`sourceSet`](https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html).

In `build.gradle.kts`:

1. Add flags for manually specifying which JDK version to use:

```kotlin
var only8 = false
var only21 = false
System.getenv("only")?.let {
    when
    {
        it == "8" -> only8 = true
        it == "21" -> only21 = true
    }
}
```

2. Add both source sets for 8 and 21:

```kotlin
sourceSets {
    val java8 by creating
    val java21 by creating
}
```

3. Add dependencies for `main` `sourceSet`:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    if (only8) implementation(sourceSets.getByName("java8").output)
    if (only21) implementation(sourceSets.getByName("java21").output)
}
```

4. Remove useless `sourceSet` while packaging jar:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<Jar> {
    if (only21 and sourceSets.any { it.name.equals("java8", ignoreCase = true) }) {
        sourceSets.remove(sourceSets.getByName("java8"))
    }
    if (only8 and sourceSets.any { it.name.equals("java21", ignoreCase = true) }) {
        sourceSets.remove(sourceSets.getByName("java21"))
    }
}
```

Then, by specifying `only=8` or `only=21` environment variable while building jar, I can specify whether the compilation is done by (`src/main/java` + `src/java8/java`) or (`src/main/java` + `src/java21/java`).

- Pros: Not so hard to implement.
- Cons: File level isolation may be too thick.